# How to change mat-menu-item font size to small in Angular?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

```
<button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" mat-button>Options</button>
    <mat-menu class="mat-menu" #ServicesButton #menu="matMenu">
        <button class="mat-menu-item" mat-menu-item>Option 1</button>
        <button class="mat-menu-item" mat-menu-item>Option 2</button>
        <button class="mat-menu-item" mat-menu-item>Option 3</button>
        <button class="mat-menu-item" mat-menu-item>Option 4</button>
    </mat-menu>
```

Right now the css for this menu is angular's default. I want to change it but it's not working through css class.

I have tried using css class. No results.
I have tried inline style. I was only able to change background color. Font size is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure ? Check this.

css

```
.mat-menu-item{
  font-size: 9px;
}
```

html

```
<button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" mat-button>Options</button>
    <mat-menu class="mat-menu" #ServicesButton #menu="matMenu">
        <button class="mat-menu-item" mat-menu-item>Option 1</button>
        <button class="mat-menu-item" mat-menu-item>Option 2</button>
        <button class="mat-menu-item" mat-menu-item>Option 3</button>
        <button class="mat-menu-item" mat-menu-item>Option 4</button>
    </mat-menu>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-menu?file=app%2Fmenu-icons-example.html,app%2Fmenu-icons-example.css