# How to change mat-menu-item font size?

Tags: css, angular

I found a question about this here:

[How to change mat-menu-item font size to small in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75170757/how-to-change-mat-menu-item-font-size-to-small-in-angular)

But for me it didn't work.

I tried this code in my Angular app, but mat-menu-item font-size doesn't change at all.

**SCSS**

```scss
.mat-menu-item{
  font-size: 9px;
}
```

**Markup**

```html
<button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" mat-button>Options</button>
<mat-menu class="mat-menu" #ServicesButton #menu="matMenu">
  <button class="mat-menu-item" mat-menu-item>Option 1</button>
  <button class="mat-menu-item" mat-menu-item>Option 2</button>
  <button class="mat-menu-item" mat-menu-item>Option 3</button>
  <button class="mat-menu-item" mat-menu-item>Option 4</button>
</mat-menu>
```

I also tried the following

```html
<mat-menu class="mat-menu" #ServicesButton #menu="matMenu">
  <button style="font-size: 9px;" mat-menu-item>Option 1</button>
  <button style="font-size: 9px;" mat-menu-item>Option 2</button>
  <button style="font-size: 9px;" mat-menu-item>Option 3</button>
  <button style="font-size: 9px;" mat-menu-item>Option 4</button>
</mat-menu>
```

As an alternative, how can I recreate the `.mat-menu-item` using regular HTML such as `<li>Option 1</li><li>Option 2</li>`?

Comment: Is that CSS in the component's stylesheet or the global one? You'll likely need to disable view encapsulation on the component (bad), use `ng-deep`, or use global styles.

Comment: @Carcigenicate It's in the app.component.scss file. Added that info to the question. By the way, the css that I add into that file (or even inline like my second example) work fine for other style changes like in regular html elements. The issue is just with mat-menu-item.

Comment: Try changing the CSS selector for the ruleset to `::host :ng-deep .mat-menu-item` from just `.mat-menu-item`. Did that fix it?

Comment: I replaced ```.mat-menu-item``` to ```::host :ng-deep .mat-menu-item```. Didn't work.

Comment: Edited the question to add the following --> As an alternative, do you know what css would recreate the .mat-menu-item using a standard html ```<li>Option 1</li><li>Option 2</li>```?

Answer (score 1):

use this css rule in styles.css:

```
.mat-mdc-menu-item span{
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. I tried it in three different ways: 1. ```<button class="mat-menu-item" mat-menu-item>Option 1</button>``` 2. ```<button class="mat-mdc-menu-item" mat-menu-item>Option 1</button>```  3. ```<button mat-menu-item>Option 1</button>```

Comment: Based on this idea, I found a way that kind of worked. That is to add an span element in the menu item. Like this: ```<button class="mat-mdc-menu-item" mat-menu-item><span>Option 1</span></button>```. Then it indeed changed the font size. But the problem is that the row top and bottom margins didn't change in the same proportion. Tried changing margin and padding both for ```.mat-mdc-menu-item span``` and for ```.mat-mdc-menu-item``` with no effect. But it is better already.